# Looking for SQL-Query to select images with similar colors

Tags: sql, sqlite, image-processing, colors

I created the following sqlite-DB-table and populated it with information about the frequency of different
colors of the pixels of a set of images that I analyzed. I'd like to select images according to alike colors.
I was inspired by a project by Matthew Mueller (http://research.cs.wisc.edu/vision/piximilar/), reengeneered
an alike website and am about to change the search-pattern he suggests.

Each image consists of 100 pixels and hence the sum of the columns color1 ... color6 is always 100.

```
id int | filename text | color1 int | color2 int | color3 int | color4 int | color5 int | color6 int |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      | 1.bmp         | 23         | 25         | 50         | 0          | 0          | 0          |
2      | 2.bmp         | 25         | 12         | 11         | 2          | 37         | 13         |
3      | 3.bmp         | 15         | 16         | 17         | 18         | 19         | 15         |
4      | 4.bmp         | 0          | 100        | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          |
...
```

I'm trying to write an SQL query to select all tuples where

a) **one of any of the columns has a frequency above a certain threshold.**
Example with DB above: threshold = 40 --> rows with ids 1 and 4 are selected.

b) **the sum of two of any of the columns is above a certain threshold.**
Example with DB above: threshold = 60 --> rows with ids 1, 2 and 4 are returned

c) **rows are sorted according to how «close» / «similar» they are to a certain tuple.**
Example with DB above: «closeness» to id 2 is goal:
Resulting order: 2, 3, 1, 4

I would appreciate your suggestions for good queries a, b and c very much.
Thanks, Dani

Comment: For a, you want "where color1 > 40 or color2 > 40 etc"  For b, you want something similar, but with every 2 column combination available.  c is too difficult for my meager talents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your queries will be easier to write if you normalize your tables

```
files

file_id, filename
1, 1.bmp
2, 2.bmp

file_colors

file_id, color_id, color_value
1, 1, 23
1, 2, 25
1, 3, 50
1, 4, 0
1, 5, 0
```

a) Any 1 color above a certain value

```
select file_id from file_colors
group by file_id
having count(case when color_value >= 40 then 1 end) > 0
```

b) Any sum of 2 colors above a certain value

```
select distinct file_id from file_colors t1
join file_colors t2 on t1.file_id = t2.file_id
where t1.color_id <> t2.color_id
and t1.color_value + t2.color_value >= 60
```

c) You didn't define 'difference'. The query below calculates it as the sum of the absolute distance for each color.

```
select t1.file_id
from file_colors t1
join file_colors t2 on t2.file_id = 2 and t2.color_id = t1.color_id
group by t1.file_id
order by sum(abs(t1.color_value - t2.color_value))
```

Comment: That sound's great, I'll normalize my db and will try it out and get back to you, thank's a lot!

Comment: I was able to confirm that a) and b) work as wished. c) however seems to ignore the color information of the mentioned file (file_id = 2 in your answer) but the list of images given back always starts at complete uniform pictures (e.g. blue sky, dark night). I actually used the following query:
select files.file_id, files.filename as dateiname from files join file_colors t1 on t1.file_id = files.file_id join file_colors t2 on t2.color_id = t1.color_id and t2.file_id = 250 group by t1.file_id order by sum(abs(t1.color_anzahl - t2.color_anzahl)) limit 100; and got:http://wunderwald.ch/pics/l.png

Comment: Do you have another suggestion for a query to list images that have almost the same color pixel counts as the first image (top left, file_id = 250 in my example)? Thanks.